# How to separate JSON data that has been grouped together in a jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jQuery that retrieves data from a JSON server and prints it out into a "output" variable. It looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/getTest/', showTodo);
    function showTodo(data) {
    var output = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {

        output += item.testName;

        $(".studentlink").append('<li><a href="http://www.u2.com/index/home">' + output + '</a></li>');
    });
  }
});
```

The foreach loop that is in the function handles the output variable. This .js file is for a navigationbar. When I launch the website it looks like this:

item_1
    
 ------ 
    item_2 
    item_3
    
 ------ 
    item_4 
    item_5 
    item_6

But I want each element in the navigationbar to be separated. How do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is going to grow with each element of the array appended to it. I think what you are looking for is to add item.testName as a list item.

If you format your appending string you will notice elements dont match up

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.u2.com/index/home"> //output 
    </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

There is

```
</div>
```

with no

```
<div>
```

This makes more sense to me

```
$(".studentlink").append('<li><a href="http://www.u2.com/index/home">' + item.testName + '</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to comment due to my fewer points so I am writing you an answer.

You are adding (or concatenating) result in "output" variable.
In addition, you are appending each data from the array to the list in this line : `$(".studentlink").append('<li><a href="http://www.u2.com/index/home">' + output + '</div></a></li>');`

I think you need to add just `item.testName` while appending a list.
Or you can write this line 
`$(".studentlink").append('<li><a href="http://www.u2.com/index/home">' + output + '</div></a></li>');` after the for each loop.

Comment: Your answer solved the problem! I appreciate it! Thank you!